# Visual Studio 2013 requires admin right?

Tags: visual-studio

I would prefer to run Visual Studio 2013 with user privilege but it gives me error "Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application". I never installed it as an administrator. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, i'm running mine in a normal user Environment - no Problems at all - but take a look into the logging i'd say.

Comment: Where can I find the log files?

Comment: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Version>\ActivityLog.XML it migth be that you have to start it with \log switch

Comment: And what is I need to look for in the file?

Comment: My user didn't has sufficient priviledge:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932319/visual-studio-2010-the-application-data-folder-for-visual-studio-cannot-be-crea#comment9691178_7932396.